# Foundationpress - How can i style foundation components?

Tags: wordpress, sass, zurb-foundation

I'm new to Foundationpress and I want to change the style of components like Tabs and breadcrumbs.
I have tried to copy scss files from 'my-theme/assets/components/foundation-sites/scss/components' to 'my-theme/assets/scss/components' and import this file in foundation.scss file:
@import "components/breadcrumbs";

It doesn't work. What should I do in order to style this components?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all your development enviroment *should* be using Gulp (used on Foundationpress) to build SASS files (If you're not, I'd recommend to take a look to Foundationpress readme at https://github.com/olefredrik/FoundationPress , it's quite straightforward, there you have all commands available on the gulpfile.

Now, about the styling... I'd recommend first taking a look to the Foundation's settings file, which you can see at `[theme root]/scss/config/_settings.scss` (maybe you'd want to use `[theme root]/scss/config/_custom-settings.scss`

In the config file, locate the component you'd want to customize, most of the time, the customizations can be achieved just modifying the variables at the config file (Foundation is quite customizable), remember to build the theme (or using the watch task) when you do the edits, so the CSS is generated properly.

If you need deeper changes, you could write your overrides in your custom sass file; I won't recommend override the entire component sass file because that can bring issues upon framework update.

Hope this helps.